# How to get stack size of a systemc thread?

Tags: c++, pthreads, stack-overflow, systemc

Is there a SystemC API that gets current SC thread stack size ?

I know you can set the stack size through `set_stack_size` and `sc_spawn_options`. But cannot find an API for getting it.

Comment: There's two questions mixed in there. Please try to limit to one question at a time. This reduces the chance of getting closed as too broad.

Comment: Why would you need to query the stack size of a SystemC thread?  What can you do with this information, other than printing it out? If it is about detecting stack overflows, there are other solutions around.

Comment: @pah Thanks for the comment. Yes it is about detecting stack overflow in a SystemC thread. What other solutions could be for this purpose ? Is it different from detecting stack overflows for pthreads ?. Many Thanks.

Comment: The question about detecting stack overflows in a SystemC thread should probably move to a separate question, which we can then link from here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to query the stack size of a SystemC thread in IEEE Std. 1666-2011 (or any implementation I'm aware of).

There are probably two aspects here:

1. Not all underlying thread implementations provide such APIs and requiring an API for SystemC would make SystemC implementations more complicated.
2. What would be the need for such an API? For which use cases you need to know the stack size of a SystemC thread during run-time?